# CoffeeScript: how to do f(a(1), b(2), c(3)) braceless style?

Tags: coffeescript

```
f5 = (x) -> 500 + x
f6 = (x) -> 600 + x
f7 = (x) -> 700 + x
console.log (f5 5, f6 6, f7 7)             # prints 505
console.log(f5 5, f6 6, f7 7)              # prints 505
console.log f5 5, f6 6, f7 7               # prints 505
console.log(f5(5), f6(6), f7(7))
```

Only the last call to `console.log` is working as expected: `505 606 707` is printed.
But that is JavaScript style (or should I mention Lisp?), can the same be achieved in CoffeeScript style?

Comment: You cannot eliminate all the braces from this statement as the compiler does not know which scope the commas belong to.

Comment: `()` are parentheses, `{}` are braces, `[]` are brackets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see two solution for your problem.

First one is to use parentheses:

```
console.log (f5 5), (f6 6), (f7 7)
```

Second one is to split your `console.log` into multiple lines:

```
console.log (f5 5),
  f6 6
  f7 7
```

Unfortunately, the first argument of your function should be on the same line as the function itself. It means that there is no way to get rid of parentheses completely in your example.

Comment: why `console.log (f5 5) (f6 6) (f7 7)` is giving a TypeError?

Comment: Because you missed commas. `(f6 6) (f7 7)` means a function call where `(f6 6)` is a function and `(f7 7)` is its argument.

Answer (score 1):

This is what your code translates to:

```
var f5, f6, f7;

f5 = function(x) {
  return 500 + x;
};

f6 = function(x) {
  return 600 + x;
};

f7 = function(x) {
  return 700 + x;
};

console.log(f5(5, f6(6, f7(7))));  //505
console.log(f5(5, f6(6, f7(7))));  //505
console.log(f5(5, f6(6, f7(7))));  //505
console.log(f5(5), f6(6), f7(7));  //505, 606, 707
```

So in your 1st **3** logs you are calling `f5` which only takes in **one** parameter therefore the rest of the arguments are ignored.

---

What you **can** do is this:

```
console.log(
   f5 5
   f6 6
   f7 7 
 )
```

The multiple lines forces it to run as individual functions

You can do the same for objects, putting newlines adds a comma:

```
obj = 
    a: 42
    b: 23
```

Comment: So your answer is "no, you can't" ?

Comment: Nope. @exebook updating now :-)

Comment: There is an alternative solution: `console.log (f5 5), (f6 6), (f7 7)`

Comment: Still some braces are present in both qwertynl and Leonid answers!

Answer (score 0):

The central problem is that once you've given it:

```
console.log f5 5  # compiles to console.log(f5(5));
```

there isn't a way of adding another argument (e.g. `f6(6)` or even just `6`) to `console.log` without `()`.  Every thing that I try with newlines, commas and indents either gives errors or produces

```
console.log(f5(5, f6(6)));
```

In other words, how do you unambiguously tell it that `f6 6` is an argument to `console.log` rather than `f5`?  Coffeescript does not analyse those functions to determine how many arguments each can take.  In fact in Javascript, and by extension Coffeescript, functions do not have a fixed signature.

Besides asking what the compiler will handle, ask what is clear to you?  If you saw:

```
foo one two, three four
```

and didn't know anything about those variables, how would you interpret it?